# radio button value cant send via mail

Tags: php, jquery, html

First radio button only taken

```
     <div class="field_radio" name="preference" >
       <input class="radio1" type="radio" name="preference" id="preference" 
         value="team"  onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /><label for="radio1">
         <span>Team</span></label>
      <input class="radio2" type="radio" name="preference" id="preference" 
         value="individual" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" /> <label for="radio2">
         <span>Individual</span></label>
     </div>
```

Php section

```
if (empty($_POST["preference"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "preference is required ";
} else {
    $preference = $_POST["preference"];
}
```

Comment: name attribute is not allowed on div element

Comment: i think its because of same id of the radio button please change id of second radio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you took same id on both input field

```
<div class="field_radio" name="preference">
    <input class="radio1" type="radio" name="preference" id="preference_one"         value="team"  onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    <input class="radio2" type="radio" name="preference" id="preference_two" 
     value="individual" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
</div>
```

Comment: but my form-scripts.js like 
function submitForm(){
    var preference = $("#Preference1").val(); 
    //  var preference2 = $("#Preference2").val(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
          data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&preference=" + 
 preference + "&teams=" + teams + "&phone=" + phone + "&pledge=" + pledge,

Comment: yes also change in your script #preference1 replace with preference_one and also #preference2 replace with preference_two

Comment: i changed   var preference = $("#preference_one").val(); 
var preference_two = $("#preference_two").val(); 

data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&preference=" + preference + "&preference=" + preference_two + "&teams=" + teams + "&phone=" + phone + "&pledge=" + pledge,   but same result
if (empty($_POST["preference"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "preference is required ";
} else {
    $preference = $_POST["preference"];
}    mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $preference, "From:".$email);...

Comment: brother, you are using $preference in mail why use this replace $preference with $message

Comment: for mail function use you code format like this <?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = $preference;

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>

Comment: like this $message = "$preference". "$preference_tow"; don't use $preference in mail function

Comment: i changed like this ..now its working...thanks for your valuable comments

    var radio_button_value;
             if ($("input[name='preference']:checked").length > 0){
                  radio_button_value = 
                 $('input:radio[name=preference]:checked').val();
           }
           else{
               alert("No button selected, try again!");
               return false;
           }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
          data: "name=" "&preference=" + radio_button_value

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field_radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio1" name="preference" id="preference1" value="team" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    <label for="radio1"><span>Team</span></label>
    <input type="radio" class="radio2" name="preference" id="preference2" value="individual" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    <label for="radio2"><span>Individual</span></label>
</div>
```

Note: Ids of the radio buttons are same make it different will solve your problem!

Comment: can someone explain me why i got minus?

Comment: I guess because you use different name values? They need to match in order to work right. And also even if it was right, would be nice to explain the OP what you did and why.

Comment: Here we are to help each other !answer updated with explanation :-)